# Only last value returned in an associative array

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, multidimensional-array, foreach

Here is my code that I am working on to create an array so the end product will return the following:

```
 $values=user_email => displayname
         user_email => displayname
         user_email => displayname
```

I am using the array listed below:

```
array [0] => std.class Object( [id] = 12
                               [user_login] = bob
                             )
      [1] => std.class Object( [id] = 15
                               [user_login] = frank
                              )
```

When I run my code that is listed below it only runs on the last value. I have tried using the "." at the variable name but it only seems to add it to the variable instead of the array where I need it.

What I hope to do is:

- Run a wp_user_query to return all the personnel in a group
- get the results
- after I get the results, use the [id] for each user to determine their $displayname and $email
- they are then sent into a new array using their email as key

Here is the code that I have been working on, and as of right now it does everything correctly except return every user, it only returns the last user

```
function show_user_dropdown($values, $field){
  if( $field->id == 155 ){   
    $wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Hrrepresentative', 'fields' => array('user_login', 'ID') ) );  
    $authors = $wp_user_search->get_results();
    $value['options']=array();
    foreach ($authors as $a) {
      $displayname=get_the_author_meta('display_name', $a->ID); 
      $emailname=get_the_author_meta('user_email', $a->ID); 
      $validation=array($emailname=>$displayname);
      $values['options']=$validation;                                                           
      $values['use_key'] = true;
    }

  }
  return $values;
}
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: **Please indent your code!** It is unreadable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the array structure you showed, try:

```
$values['options'][$emailname] = $displayname;
```

Comment: This was the exact change that I needed to make and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have both 'values' and 'value'.  I don't think the array notation is working how you think it is.  I think you'd be better off doing something like this:

```
$values[$id]['option'] = $validation;
```

edit: to elaborate, you only have 1 value for $values (the last run through the foreach loop).   You also would be overwriting the previous value in $values['option'] regardless.  You need to use a multidimensional array with an index.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `$values['options']=$validation;` in your loop.

Use it this way:

```
$values['options'][]=$validation;
```